# What kind of uses could you get out of a humanoid mech/robot on the moon?

Tags: robotics

Edit: A humanoid mech like the ones in Avatar or a mecha from the Patlabor anime. Something that's roughly around the size of both.

Comment: If you want legged robots, then a centaur-type quadruped with manipulator arms might be a better idea. But on the Moon, wheels will be even better. The bipedal humanoid shape is very good for climbing and crawling and handling irregularities like steps, but not so great for moving around in the open, not compared to wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the level of technology currently available for humanoid type robots,  such robots are not well suited for usage on the Moon or elsewhere. They have limited functionality.

The types of wheeled probes that were used on the Moon by [the Soviets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunokhod_programme) and are currently being used on [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)) achieved a lot and will continue to do so. They are generally easily maneuverable and their size provides a good platform for many scientific instruments and other tools they may be required.

There is potential for [legged robots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legged_robot) to explore the Moon and other celestial bodies. Compared to wheeled robots/probes, legged ones have the potential to travel rough and steep terrain. Before they can be used they would need to have a level of artificial intelligence that would recognize hazardous terrain, such as a loose sandy or rocky slopes, and be able to react very quickly and independently.